# Disconnected LINQ Updates: rowversion vs. datetime with trigger?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, concurrency, rowversion

We're using LINQ to SQL and WCF for a new middle tier, and we're using Data Transfer Objects for passing over the wire rather than using the actual LINQ classes.  I'm going to be using one or the other of the methods outlined here - [Linq Table Attach() based on timestamp or row version](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2007/12/18/117823.aspx) - in order to ensure that updates work correctly and that concurrency is handled correctly.

To save you folks some reading time, essentially you can either use a timestamp/rowversion column in your table or have a datetime column with a default and an update trigger - either way it gets you a column that gets a newly generated value each time an insert or update occurs, and that column is the one used by LINQ to check for concurrency.

My question is - which one is better?  We already have datetime columns for "UpdatedWhen" in many of our tables (but not all - don't ask), but would be adding in the defaults and the triggers, or we could just add the rowversion (we'd have to use the timestamp syntax for now, since we're still supporting SQL2005 for a while) to each table - either way we're modifying the DB in order to make it work, so I'd like to know whether there's a performance difference or any other important difference to note between these two alternatives.  I've tried searching the web and here on SO, but no luck so far.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would lean towards using timestamp column for concurrency checks. One - triggers would have some impact upon performance and two - with date time column you'll be limiting yourself to the precision of DateTime column in SQL and C#.

**MSDN:**

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds...

You may want to look at [SO: Is there any difference between DateTime in c# and DateTime in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181662/is-there-any-difference-between-datetime-in-c-and-datetime-in-sql-server) and [MSDN: datetime (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I would agree - multiple, rapid updates can in fact receive the same datetime values. The time stamp (rowversion) is definitely going to be different each time. I can't speak to performance, but I know that rowversion works well. I combine rowversion with Identity columns, and always pass at least those two parts in my DTOs

Answer (score 4):

I had to make the similar decision recently.

I tried rowversion solution first.
The disadvantages that I found:

- Inconvenient usages in LINQ-to-SQL, I mapped the field to byte[]. The code does not look clean when you compare byte arrays
- Theoretically `rowversion` can roll over and start from 0 again, so row with higher `rowversion` will not necessarily be older row
- Rowversion is updated on any row update, which in my case was not desirable, I needed to exclude some columns to not affect row version. Having a trigger allows to implement any level of flexibility.

As a result I used datetime2 column with a default constraint and update trigger to set the value to sysutcdatetime()
.
This type has accuracy 100 nanoseconds (precision 7 digits - 23:59:59.9999999)
.
Although it is possible, I never saw generation of the same value twice yet. But in my case it will not hurt if there will be duplicates. If it was important to me, I would add unique constraint, and see if this ever fails.

I used sysutcdatetime() as this value would not be affected by daylight saving.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience - although I'm not sure which way we'll go yet, it's helpful to have some actual information based on real usage of both sides.

Comment: Why are you comparing the byte arrays in your code?  Doesn't LINQ-to-SQL just send the value from the rowversion column as part of the WHERE clause when you do an update?

Comment: In LINQ-to-SQL it works, but it doesn't if you materialized results. Can cause subtle bugs.