# entity framework on entering a datetime 1 millisecond before the next day date is getting rounded up

Tags: entity-framework

I'm entering a datetime using the entity framework and I was trying to enter this date:

```
new DateTime(2011, 11, 18, 23, 59, 59, 999);
```

which is one millisecond before the 19th.

However when I check it in the database it keeps getting rounded up to the 19th 2011/11/19 0 0 0 000

Anyone know what's going on here and how to remedy it?

This is the type in my model:

```
public override DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your column type on database is date? not datetime

Comment: you say rounded up but rounded down

Comment: ok I see what you mean I had an error in my question. Updated.

Comment: you right, i check this with new SqlDateTime(new DateTime(2011, 11, 18, 23, 59, 59, 999)) and return your result but with 998 not rounded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181662/is-there-any-difference-between-datetime-in-c-sharp-and-datetime-in-sql-server/1181668#1181668

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've now found that I have 3 nanosecond precision and you can't even set the precision in Sql Management Studio it keeps rounding it.