# DateTime is not equal

Tags: c#, datetime

I have next code:

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
InsertIntoDatabase(endTime);
var row = Db.SelectRow("select endTime from MyTable Where @column=myval", columnValue);
Assert.Equal(row["endTime"], endTime); // This is false! Why?
```

Assert is false. 
And dates are different for some reason on milliseconds. Why???

endTime:

```
Date    {7/17/2015 12:00:00 AM} System.DateTime
        Day 17  int
        DayOfWeek   Friday  System.DayOfWeek
        DayOfYear   198 int
        Hour    1   int
        Kind    Unspecified System.DateTimeKind
        Millisecond 370 int
        Minute  21  int
        Month   7   int
        Second  27  int
        Ticks   635726928873700000  long
+       TimeOfDay   {01:21:27.3700000}  System.TimeSpan
        Year    2015    int
```

row["endTime"]:

```
Date    {7/17/2015 12:00:00 AM} System.DateTime
        Day 17  int
        DayOfWeek   Friday  System.DayOfWeek
        DayOfYear   198 int
        Hour    1   int
        Kind    Local   System.DateTimeKind
        Millisecond 371 int
        Minute  21  int
        Month   7   int
        Second  27  int
        Ticks   635726928873716049  long
+       TimeOfDay   {01:21:27.3716049}  System.TimeSpan
        Year    2015    int
```

WHY???

Comment: These two `DateTimes` are not equal. Look at the `Ticks` on both.

Comment: Even their `Ticks` are not equal.

Comment: `DateTime` should be the same, are you sure you are using passed parameter and not something else in `InsertIntoDataBase`?

Comment: In your Database, use a `Datetime2` (100ns precision) instead of a `Datetime` (3ms precision) => [ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnsoldevs/archive/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [this (Difference between DateTime in c# and DateTime in SQL server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181662/is-there-any-difference-between-datetime-in-c-and-datetime-in-sql-server) will help a little.

you can also use Datetime2 for SQL

Comment: This is the "real" answer, but maybe you could explain with a little more details

Comment: yeah i can, but i think post by post, may be it will modify and that is why i point it to original post. :)

Comment: Yes, but you should include some TL;DR at least. it shouldn't happen, but if the original answer is deleted, then this post would be useless

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate instead then, instead of linking to a post in an answer.

Comment: Okay next time i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a rounding error to me, the `DateTime` has ticks of `635726928873700000` whereas the `Row` has `635726928873716049`. This is probably due to differing levels of precision in the database vs DateTime.

The differences in ticks means they are different DateTimes.