# Checking database with date part only on ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I am stuck by a situation and can't move forward. I will explain my scenario.

I have a date column in my database. I'm using a code-first approach. Now when someone adds a new date using `DateTime.Now` I want to check the database to count how many rows of data are added with today's date. If it's 5 I want to show an error message to the user who is trying to add new data today. But I can't check today's data as datetime always give result with time.

My date model property is

```
 public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

Current to code achieve the above is

```
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;

var dateresult = dbcontext.Appointments.Where(q => q.Date == date2).Count();

if (ModelState.IsValid && result == 0 && dateresult <= 5)
{}
```

but the count doesn't return the result. It is always zero.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this? How to get today's data without comparing time part? I have searched many but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: You can check whether the date is between today 00:00 and tomorrow 00.00, if you dont want to format the datetime

Comment: cn u please provide me the example code.
is there any problem from the dataformat string in model property?

Comment: You have posted the definition of `Appointments.AppointmentTime` not `Appointments.Date`?

Comment: oops sry! I have updated my question.

Comment: Good, then you can create two plain `datetimes` with today's and tomorrow's date at 0.00 and change your query to `Where(q => q.Date >= today && q.Date < tomorrow)`

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Please see the 2nd answer in the marked duplicate. Also you can simplify your expressions by replacing `Where` with `Count` (*and then remove Count() at the end*)

Comment: Niklas that worked!

Comment: Igor I had went through all that answers early but that couldnt resolve my issue. I couldn't get data based on datetime as it always returna time even in datetime.date which is 12.00.00. so i couldnt find a methos that properly removes timepart. but this comparison of 2 dates taht is today n tomorrow solved! thank you guys !

Comment: That is because you are comparing incorrectly. Get only the date first using *Today*: `DateTime date2 = DateTime.Today;` Then compare by truncating the time: `var dateresult = dbcontext.Appointments.Count(q => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Date) == date2);`

Comment: that too worked! :D but in the link you provided there is no answer using appointments.count. anyway thanks. Which of these 2 answer would be best to use?

Comment: Use what ever one works best for you, I doubt there is much, if any, difference in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting DateTime to Date , check if database date falls between today's 12 midnight  to tomorrow midnight(exclusive) as shown below

use this :

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
```

and then this :

```
 var dateresult = dbcontext.Appointments.Where(q => q.Date >= today && q.Date < tomorrow).Count();
```

Comment: tried these from other answers but not getting value.. the time property will be 00 or 12 so when searching its searches for time with 00 or 12.

Comment: i have updated my response ! have a look

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: that worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: DateTime date2 = DateTime.Today; Then compare by truncating the time: var dateresult = dbcontext.Appointments.Count(q => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Date) == date2);  this is also right!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the column name is correct in the Appointment table which is storing the date value for example if the column name is Todaysdate , you have to use below code

```
var dateresult = dbcontext.Appointments.Where(q => q.Todaysdate == date2).Count();
```

Comment: that was a mistake. column name is date. i have updated my question. the date column is of type datatime?..

Comment: I believe the issue is due to datatype datetime incompatibility between sql and c# , Hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181662/is-there-any-difference-between-datetime-in-c-sharp-and-datetime-in-sql-server helps